# How can I download the DESCRIPTION for fields in an access-web-app?

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc, ms-access-web-app

In Access-Web-Apps, there's three columns to define for each field in a table: the name, the field type and an optional description. I would like to download the "DESCRIPTION" component of each field for a given table.

In R, using the command `sqlColumns()` from the package `RODBC`, I am able to obtain the structure of my table. The fields that it returns are:

```
sqlColumns(channel,"XXX") %>% dplyr::names
 [1] "TABLE_CAT"                            "TABLE_SCHEM"                          "TABLE_NAME"                          
 [4] "COLUMN_NAME"                          "DATA_TYPE"                            "TYPE_NAME"                           
 [7] "COLUMN_SIZE"                          "BUFFER_LENGTH"                        "DECIMAL_DIGITS"                      
[10] "NUM_PREC_RADIX"                       "NULLABLE"                             "REMARKS"                             
[13] "COLUMN_DEF"                           "SQL_DATA_TYPE"                        "SQL_DATETIME_SUB"                    
[16] "CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH"                    "ORDINAL_POSITION"                     "IS_NULLABLE"                         
[19] "SS_IS_SPARSE"                         "SS_IS_COLUMN_SET"                     "SS_IS_COMPUTED"                      
[22] "SS_IS_IDENTITY"                       "SS_UDT_CATALOG_NAME"                  "SS_UDT_SCHEMA_NAME"                  
[25] "SS_UDT_ASSEMBLY_TYPE_NAME"            "SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_CATALOG_NAME" "SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_SCHEMA_NAME" 
[28] "SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_NAME"         "SS_DATA_TYPE"
```

But the I see that there is a `REMARKS` column, but nothing else resembling a description. The Remarks column is empty... is there any way to capture this information? (Using RODBC in R or any other software package).

### Edit: Showing screenshots

Here is proof that a table has descriptions, but nothing is coming through in R. (Sorry for terrible screenshot, don't want to show too much of my structure).
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have non-blank items in field description? Just tested and all description items shows in `REMARKS` column.

Comment: @Parfait interesting! Yes, I'm sure there's data there... what version Webapps were you using? Anything you can recommend for me to try?

Comment: Access web apps are essentially the same as desktop apps (same file type .accdb) except they are compliant over the web with reduced features. On desktop, open this .accdb file and screenshot the design view of this table so we can see entry in `DESCRIPTION` section.

Comment: @Parfait, screenshot added

Comment: Interesting. Can you import this table (External Tools tab) to a blank Access desktop .accdb and recreate the issue? Again, I cannot from desktop app (no Office 365/Sharepoint server to test web app).

Comment: Good call! When I built a direct link to the table, it accepts the connection, but omits the details! So I guess details just live in the online one... let's see if anyone has any other ideas

Comment: I meant create a second Access **desktop** .accdb with exact table and then run an RODBC connection on it (no linked table) and see if `REMARKS` remain empty. I believe the web app version may strip out the `DESCRIPTION` meta data.

Comment: oh... I see... well.. I kinda don't care if it does :) I need the descriptions offa the web databases.